# container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration) causes InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

In my integration tests I'm using the same SimpleInjector.Container which I construct in the Web API project I'm testing.

But this line in composition root class:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

causes an exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'MyProject.Api.Test.Integration.HttpClientFactory' threw an exception.
---- System.InvalidOperationException : This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.
Result StackTrace:  
at MyProject.Api.Test.Integration.HttpClientFactory.Create()
   at MyProject.Api.Test.Integration.Controllers.ProductControllerIntegrationTest.<GetProductBarcode_Should_Return_Status_BadRequest_When_Barcode_Is_Empty>d__0.MoveNext() in d:\Projects\My\MyProject.Api.Test.Integration\Controllers\ProductControllerIntegrationTest.cs:line 26
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostAssembliesResolver.System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IAssembliesResolver.GetAssemblies()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorWebApiExtensions.GetControllerTypesFromConfiguration(HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorWebApiExtensions.RegisterWebApiControllers(Container container, HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at MyProject.Api.ContainerConfig.RegisterTypes(Container container) in d:\Projects\My\MyProject.Api\App_Start\ContainerConfig.cs:line 128
   at MyProject.Api.ContainerConfig.CreateWebApiContainer() in d:\Projects\My\MyProject.Api\App_Start\ContainerConfig.cs:line 63
   at MyProject.Api.Test.Integration.HttpClientFactory..cctor() in d:\Projects\My\MyProject.Api.Test.Integration\HttpClientFactory.cs:line 17
```

After commenting it everything works fine, both the web app itself and the tests.

So the question is:

- What is the reason for the exception?
- (And is this method really required?)

Here's the code for HttpClientFactory (a helper class to create HttpClient with proper headers, such as api key or authorization):

```
internal static class HttpClientFactory
{
    private static readonly Container _container = ContainerConfig.CreateWebApiContainer();

    public static HttpClient Create()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = GetUrl() };
        //...
        return client;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the InnerException and StackTrace details? Do you have some binding redirects in your config file?

Comment: I agree with @DarinDimitrov, please give us the full stack trace. It's hard to reason about this without these details.

Comment: @Darin: Updated, thanks! Binding redirects are very similar to what I have in Web.config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look closely at the stack trace we can exactly see what is going on here. The `RegisterWebApiControllers` extension method calls the `GetControllerTypes` method on the `IHttpControllerTypeResolver` instance it grabs from the `HttpConfiguration` and it passes the `IAssembliesResolver` that is also retrieved from the configuration. The called `GetControllerTypes` method (of the `WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver`) calls into the `GetControllerTypes` of the `DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver` which will eventually cause a call to `GetReferencedAssemblies` of the `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager` class.

The `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager` however, can not be called early in the ASP.NET pipeline, or outside the context of ASP.NET at all. Since you're in a test, the `BuildManage` will throw the exception you are experiencing.

So the solution (or 'trick' so you will) here is to replace the default `IAssembliesResolver` when unit testing. I imagine that resolver to look like this:

```
public class TestAssembliesResolver : IAssembliesResolver
{
    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Replace the original IAssembliesResolver.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver),
        new TestAssembliesResolver());

    var container = SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer.BuildContainer();

    container.Verify();
}
```

It's a bit unfortunate that you have to deal this, especially since Simple Injector was designed to be testable. It seems that we overlooked this by integrating the `RegisterWebApiControllers` extension method so deeply with Web API. We have to take a step back and think about how to make it easier to verify the Web API configuration inside a unit test.

Comment: Hi Steven, I saw you recently released the new version of Web Api integration package but this problem wasn't fixed yet.

Comment: @abatishchev: that's correct. v2.6.2 of the Web API integration package solely fixes the problem states [here](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/20987). For now, you'll have to do with the workaround described in my answer, or write your own custom controller registration instead of calling `RegisterWebApiControllers`.

Comment: Hi Steven, do you have any news/plans on fixing this issue, please?

Comment: Since v2.7 there's a `RegisterWebApiControllers` overload that accepts a list of assemblies. This and the method described above can be used to allow integration testing.

Comment: Oh, cool. My workaround isn't needed anymore! Can you add an overload it `params Assembly[] assemblies`? I can create a PR if you will.

Comment: @abatishchev: Neh, [not needed](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/commit/fc1e1a638e45dc6bd7c3669c3a2e632094c62647).

Comment: Push a new version then? ;)

Comment: @abatishchev v3 will be released soon.

Answer (score 4):

A solution for SI v3.x is just ...

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, 
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
);
```

.. so now it knows the assembly to search for controllers.

Comment: but how does this affect performance in light of what https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=net-6.0 says: `For performance reasons, you should call this method only when you do not know at design time what assembly is currently executing. The recommended way to retrieve an Assembly object that represents the current assembly is to use the Type.Assembly property of a type found in the assembly,`