# Web Api Unit Test Issues with Simple Injector

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, nunit, simple-injector

I'm having an issue getting my nunit tests to run after plugging in Simple Injector to my api project.  Any reference to a Service isn't working as if they aren't being loaded properly.  I attempted to load my container in my test like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704486/container-registerwebapicontrollersglobalconfiguration-configuration-causes-in)

Services are still not loading correctly.

I am running the tests in memory and they are coming back with an internal server error as soon as the first Service is referenced.  The Services that are failing first are referenced using the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IExampleService));` method and those are all coming back as null.  I tried calling the service directly in my test and it is also coming back as null, even after the container is built.

We are building the Simple Injector container using the same method in our web project and the test are having no issue referencing the services which is making me wonder if the in memory tests are the issue.

Update: The full stack trace was requested.

Initially I was getting this Exception:

> {"The service type IApiService is not supported.\r\nParameter name: serviceType"}
>         at System.Web.Http.Services.DefaultServices.GetService(Type serviceType)
>         at Project.Api.Tests.Helpers.HttpRequestHelper.CreateRequest(String url,
>        HttpMethod method, String key1, String key2, String secret, String baseUrl) 
>       in ...Project.web\src\Project.Api.Tests\Helpers\HttpRequestHelper.cs:line 537

Then moving this service logic into my test and attempting to create the container in my test I receive this:

> System.InvalidOperationException : This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase. Please note that the RegisterWebApiControllers(Container, HttpConfiguration) overload makes use of the configured IAssembliesResolver. Web API's default IAssembliesResolver uses the System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager, which can't be used in the pre-start initialization phase or outside the context of ASP.NET (e.g. when running unit tests). Either make sure you call the RegisterWebApiControllers method at a later point in time, register a custom IAssembliesResolver that does not depend on the BuildManager, or supply a list of assemblies manually using the RegisterWebApiControllers(Container, HttpConfiguration, IEnumerable) overload.

And after following the instructions in above mentioned post I received:

> {[StackTrace, at Project.Api.Filters.HmacAuthenticationAttribute.
>       d__1.MoveNext() in ...\Project.web\src\Project.Api\Filters\HmacAuthenticationAttribute.cs:line 77
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>       at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()]}

And that line reference is from this line in the code:

```
IExampleService _exampleService = (IExampleService)GlobalConfiguration
    .Configuration
    .DependencyResolver
    .GetService(typeof (IExampleService));
if (_exampleService.CheckValue(value))
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: @qujck I have updated the question with the requested information.  Let me know if you were looking for anything else.  And thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the exception pretty much explains the problem and how to solve it. You're welcome :)

Comment: Which of the two lines `... _exampleService = (IExampleService) ...` or `... _exampleService.CheckValue ...` is failing? Stack trace points to `HmacAuthenticationAttribute`.

Comment: The second line is where the exception is thrown.  The first line is returning null so technically that is failing too just not throwing the exception.  The referenced lines are from `HmacAuthenticationAttribute` but removing the problem lines just causes it to fail on the next service call.  It seems to be any service, not a specific service.

Comment: @qujck Sorry, I forgot to tag you in my response yesterday.  Just wanted to make sure you were able to see it.

Comment: @Steven the last exception isn't clear to me.  To me all that is saying is my services aren't being injected properly and I'm not sure what the resolution is.  If you could provide any further explanation that would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The exception is explaining that you can't use Web API's dedault configuration during ujit testing. This has nothing to do with Simple Injector, but SI does tell you what's wrong. You will have to implement a custom IAssembliesResolver imlentation that will return the application assemblies that contain the Web API controllers. This resolver needs to be used in your unit test suite.

Comment: SimpleInjector will not return null when a service is requested; are you sure you have registered the `SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver`?

Comment: @Steven and @qujck , both of those solutions appear to have helped, thank you!  Now when my test goes to call the controller I get the `Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.` error.  It looks like my controller isn't being registered correctly with the dependencies.  I am going to submit another question as it appears to not be related to this original question.